# Is it the best way to handle several ComboBoxes in Python GTK+?

Tags: python, pygtk

I am trying to write some configuration GUI, which as many GUIs got two or more ComboBoxes, and other stuff. I don't like copying stuff and making it everywhere the same, long, and hardly readable.
I wanna ask you about your own word in that question, is it good to create sotcha classes, and if not, how to handle it better?

./listaRozwijana-experymentalne.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Author: Camelek.AmigaRulez
# License: Public Domain
# Date: poniedziałek, 14 listopad 2011 15:41:36
#

import gtk, gobject

class KlasaComboBox():
    def __init__(self, comboboxprojekt, comboboxnazwa, comboboxlista):
        self.cmb = comboboxprojekt.get_object(comboboxnazwa);

        self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING);
        for self.wpis in comboboxlista:
            self.liststore.append([self.wpis]);

        self.cmb.set_model(self.liststore);
        self.komorka = gtk.CellRendererText();
        self.cmb.pack_start(self.komorka, True);
        self.cmb.add_attribute(self.komorka, 'text',0);

    def get_active(self):
        return(self.cmb.get_active());

    def get_active_text(self):
        return(self.cmb.get_active_text());

    def wyswietl(self):
        print 'Wybrałeś', self.cmb.get_active_text(), 'jego indeks na tej liście to:', self.cmb.get_active();

class KlasaGlowna():
    def __init__(self):
        self.projekt = gtk.Builder();
        self.projekt.add_from_file("./gui/okienkoDwochListRozwijanych.ui");

        self.okienko = self.projekt.get_object("window1");
        self.projekt.connect_signals(self);

        self.lista1 = ["Motorola 68000"];
        self.lista1.append ("Intel MCS-51");
        self.lista1.append ("Cell");
        self.lista1.append ("Zilog Z80");
        self.cmb1 = KlasaComboBox(self.projekt, "combobox1", self.lista1);

        self.lista2 = ["Pierwszy", "Drugi", "Trzeci", "Czwarty", "Piąty"];
        self.cmb2 = KlasaComboBox(self.projekt, "combobox2", self.lista2);

    def uruchom(self):
        self.okienko.show_all();
        gtk.main();

    def on_combobox1_changed(self, widget, data=None):
        self.cmb1.wyswietl();

    def on_combobox2_changed(self, widget, data=None):
        self.cmb2.wyswietl();

    def on_window1_delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = KlasaGlowna();
    app.uruchom();
else:
    sys.exit(1);
```

./gui/okienkoDwochListRozwijanych.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Wybierz sw&#xF3;j ulubiony procesor</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <signal name="delete_event" handler="on_window1_delete_event"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox2">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkVButtonBox" id="vbuttonbox1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="layout_style">spread</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkComboBox" id="combobox1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <signal name="changed" handler="on_combobox1_changed"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">False</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkComboBox" id="combobox2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <signal name="changed" handler="on_combobox2_changed"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">False</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one with this idea; [`gtk.ComboBoxText`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkcomboboxtext.html) was created to solve this problem. It is available from PyGTK 2.24 onwards. If you can't use PyGTK 2.24, then your solution seems quite reasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :] I will try to change few things about that ComboBox to make it into ComboBoxText. I heard before about ComboBoxText, but Glade dosen't offer a way to make them. I use Linux Debian Squeeze, maybe in new versions of Glade there is sotcha option to make it easy. Anyway, if I will make it I will post working example of that trick :]

Comment: @Camelek You could always just leave some places in your Glade file blank, and then add the `ComboBoxText` elements in your code. It'd only be one or two extra lines of code. The `ComboBoxText` element is very easy to manage in programatically.

Comment: Unfortunelly I will wait until Wheezy to use that glory of ComboBoxText :> Because as for now I got only version 2.17 of PyGTK+. That of course dosen't stop me, it is just another adventure on my way :D Thank you guys for quick answers :]